# read a frame and the 10th previous frame every time from a video

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have this code reading frames from a video.

```
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if frame is None:
        break
    if prev_frame is not None:
        # do something
        prev_frame = frame
```

In this code I read the current frame and I get to work on the previous frame in a simple way. How about the 10th previous frame?

Comment: You might use a 10 element array in order to keep 10th previous frame for every frame. Whenever a new frame arrives you should first discard last frame then append the new one. That way you can have both 10th previous frame for every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how u can do it. This is a simple code which takes a **list** and stores the frame in the list from 1 to 10 then when 11 frame comes it deletes the first frame and shows the 1st and 10th frame and I added time delay before **destroying** the **previous** window otherwise it will open **so** **many** **windows** or sometimes crash and sometimes works all fine just try to comment them out if it works fine for you.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import time



video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

count=0
l=[]
while True:
        
    ret, frame = video.read()
    count+=1
    l.append(frame)
    if count>10:
        cv2.imshow("1",l[10])
        cv2.imshow("10",l[0])
        l.remove(l[0])
        time.sleep(1)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```